# Changing jquery UI dialogue titlebar HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a JQuery UI dialogue and it renders the below HTML. I want the button to be wrapped in a span tag. Is there an easy way to do it while calling the dialogue.

```
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
    <span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-id-20">
    </span>
    <button title="close" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    </button>
```

Thanks

Comment: What this question has to do with the dialog title (as your post title suggests)?

Comment: use the `create` event to look for the button and wrap it then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zQm3J/))

```
var dlg = $('#d1').dialog({
    "title":"Dialog",
    "buttons":{ "OK" : function(){ $(this).dialog('close'); } }
});

// Find buttons and wrapp then with span
dlg
.closest('div.ui-dialog')
.find('button').wrap('<span class="btnWrapper"></span>');
```

BTW, you may [check this too](http://jsfiddle.net/zQm3J/1/), could be useful if you want something like this, it requires jQuery UI `version - 1.10.0`.

Comment: Sneaky down voter, gimme a reason for this so I can learn from you.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [jQuery UI documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open), you can bind an event to the `dialogopen` event:

```
$('#YourDialog').one('dialogopen',function(e,ui){
    $('button[title="close"]').wrap('<span></span>');
});
```

Notice the use of the [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function, which allows you to wrap the element selected with any HTML of your choosing. I also used `.on()` instead of `.one()` so that the event does not fire more than once (otherwise it would wrap the element every time it opened).